# What are typical internet connection speeds in Colombia?

Tags: internet, south-america, colombia

The answers will have to differ for internet cafés/hostels versus flats. I'm interested in both answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: It depends.

Long answer: If you are traveling to important cities (Bogota, Medellin, Barranquilla, Cali). The norm is a 5mbps minimum. In towns far away from main cities, could range from nightmare to 10mb. 3G coverage in most parts of the country is generally good.

Comment: Thanks! How slow does "nightmare" go? 56 kbps?

Comment: Nightmare = almost zero Internet. I've been in places where you have to climb a tree in order to get some signal to send a couple of messages.

Comment: That could also be construed as a dream =)

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Netindex list](http://www.netindex.com/download/allcountries/), where Colombia is on number 105, the average download speed is 5.45Mbps. The list doesn't distinguish between internet cafes, hostels or flats.

Comment: This list says South Korea is #3 - it always used to be #1 - have things changed or could the list be inaccurate?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is inaccurate. The speeds are registered when people measure their speeds, which usually occurs when they have problems. At least I only use their service, when being annoyed with my ISP's speed. Still I guess the ratings could act as a rough measure to compare between countries. Again as tourists who cares if South Korea is number 1 or number 3.

Comment: I seem to bring it up all the time, but I'm often a tourist in Korea and other places with slower internet and feel the need to make the comparison (-: